# Foreach keeps looping

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6.5

So i have this project that needs to print data from the database.
I do this with a simple foreach loop:

```
public void LoadDatabase()
    {
        _connection.Open();
        _dataAdapter.Fill(_dataTable);

        try
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in _dataTable.Rows)
            {
                Program.AnimalInfo.Info_ID_ListBox.Items.Add(row["Animal_ID"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to LoadDatabase()" + ex.Message);
        }
        _connection.Close();     
    }
```

The problem is that it will loop anywhere from 2 times to 6 times meaning that it prints everything at least twice.
So at the moment my database contains Animal_Id's id:1 and id:2.
Now i get in my listbox (1, 2, 1, 2) or more depending on the amount of loops. I have no idea why this is happening and how to fix this. So all help would be highly appreciated

ps: if more code or information is needed please let me know.

pss: this is for a windows mobile 6.5 device with .net 3.5 build in Visual studio 2008. also im useing sqlite (not the newest version)

EDIT: After some testing it looks like my other 2 foreach loops in this project have the same problem.

Edit: So with al you guy's help i was able to fix it.

```
public void GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            SQLiteConnection Connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = \Program Files\Mobile\Resources\Database\PPP_DB");

            Connection.Open();

            SQLiteCommand Command = new SQLiteCommand(Query, Connection);
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Data_Adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Animal_Info", Connection);
            Data_Set.Reset();
            Data_Adapter.Fill(Data_Set);
            Data_Table = Data_Set.Tables[0];

            Program.AnimalInfo.Info_ID_ListBox.Items.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow row in Data_Table.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                {
                    Program.AnimalInfo.Info_ID_ListBox.Items.Add(row["Animal_ID"].ToString());
                }
            }
            Connection.Close();
            Program.AnimalInfo.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }  
    }
```

So it seems that it messed up with the DataTable somewhere, and that made it loop multiple times. ps: i tried to set all items with stuff like Databound, but didn't really work out for me, thats the reason im still doing it this way.

Comment: Where is your `LoadDatabase` method being called from?

Comment: And what does your query look like?

Comment: THis won't address your question, but you should  put the `connection.Close();` into a finally block   `finally { _connection.Close(); }`

Comment: can do a _dataTable.clear() before filling the same?

Comment: "prints everything at least twice" where does it print?

Comment: What says Mr. Debugger?

Comment: Is there a unique constraint on "Animal_ID" field?

Comment: @Ron Byer: this function gets called when my form loads, so if correct only on startup of the app.

Comment: @Jon Skeet my querry looks like String _query = "SELECT ANIMAL_ID \"Animal_ID\",TRANSPONDER \"Transponder\",STATUS \"Status\",FEED_CURVE \"Feed_Curve\",TATTOO \"Tattoo\" FROM Animal_Info"; i thought that was the right way to do it, if not please let me know.

Comment: @Sachu i had a clear befor it already, seems like removed it but it didnt change anything if its there.

Comment: @DrKoch, in my ListBox if i look at it after my form loaded it looks something like 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 but then below eachother

Comment: @Bear, are you saying in the form load event, or somewhere else?

Comment: @Ron Beyer, Indeed in the form load event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following two lines at the top of your function.

```
Program.AnimalInfo.Info_ID_ListBox.Items.Clear();
_dataTable.Clear();
```

This will ensure that you do not double up any row data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no unique constraint on "Animal_ID" field in the database (*you din't answer to my comment*), check for items duplication:

```
if (!Program.AnimalInfo.Info_ID_ListBox.Items.Contains(row["Animal_ID"].ToString())
  Program.AnimalInfo.Info_ID_ListBox.Items.Add(row["Animal_ID"].ToString());
```

Comment: Ow im sorry didnt see your command, but there are indeed no unique constraint. something i did notice is that it my other 2 foreach loops do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, LoadDatabase() should return a DataTable (or DataSet), this make sthe LoadDatabase() function useful for other data requests,  Also you should never need to use a 'for loop' to add items to a ListBox. you can bind the ListBox directly to the source.... something like this should do it

```
listBox1.DataSource = _dataTable;
listBox1.ValueMember = "Animal_ID";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Animal_ID";
```

There are some examples using SqlDataReader and SqlDataAdapter  here http://gsidev.somee.com/#2&2AD97ECBE2AE41D08191F6E4C773D8A9&cs

Answer (score 0):

Unique contraints are not needed here. But the listbox.Items collection might have have to be cleared.

Possibly you are (or the system, depends on where the code is, for example in a paint event handler) calling the 'LoadDatabase()' function twice!

Just place a break point in the _dataAdapter.fill() and press F11 to let the app run over this and then right click the _dataTable to inspect it's contents.

Although you can explictely set the datasource of the ListBox, that is not needed and may lead to other side effects you are currently not aware of. It is OK to start with simple code before letting the system do unknwon stuff in the background.

Try that:

```
public void LoadDatabase()
{
    _connection.Open();
    _dataAdapter.Fill(_dataTable);
    Program.AnimalInfo.Info_ID_ListBox.Items.Clear();
    try
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in _dataTable.Rows)
        {
            Program.AnimalInfo.Info_ID_ListBox.Items.Add(row["Animal_ID"].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to LoadDatabase()" + ex.Message);
    }
    _connection.Close();     
}
```